# Is there a way to get Vrapper and Scala syntax highlighting?

Tags: eclipse, scala, vim

I am using Eclipse Java EE with Vrapper for working on a Java/Scala project. Is it possible to get both syntax highlighting and vrapper (or any kind of vim editing) in regular eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

You can install any plugin on any Eclipse version you want - the only requirement is that the requirement information a plugin holds are true. Each Eclipse version is just a set of plugins bundled together.

In your case, just download one of the [prepackaged Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) versions, then install the [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html) (note, that at the moment only M3 works on Luna) and finally install [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/).

Answer (score 1):

There is also eclim (http://eclim.org), a Vim/Eclipse plugin that lets you run Vim inside or alongside Eclipse and access some of the Eclipse features. But not all the Eclipse features are available from Vim, notably the debugger integration.